# Google Play App - Large Volume of "Payment Pending" Status For Subscriptions

Tags: android, payment, subscription, billing

I have recently launched an Android App with monthly and annual subscriptions. I offer a 3-day trial for each subscription level. After the 3-day trial ends, the vast majority of my monthly subscribers show "payment pending" as their payment status and are never charged. There are way too many of these "payment pending" customers for this to be a customer credit card issue. It seems to be either an issue with how we implemented the google billing library or an issue related to google pay, where customer payments are not being billed promptly. Has anyone else had the same billing issue with Android apps offering recurring monthly subscriptions?

We have reviewed the billing library but are not able to see what we may have missed. Has anyone been able to fix this issue?